# I Don't want to give file path in the code I want bytes data of the image in amazon s3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-s3

Can any one please help me.The code is working correctly for image upload but I want to give byte value in file path.Because image data type is CommonsMultipartFile.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ImageResultVO getImage(ImageCriteriaVO imageCriteriaVO) throws O2Exception, IOException
    {               
        CommonsMultipartFile file ;
        file =(CommonsMultipartFile) imageCriteriaVO.getImage();
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID") ,System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"));
          String SUFFIX = "/";
          String folderName = "images";
          String existingBucketName = "o2container";
          String keyName = folderName + SUFFIX + file.getOriginalFilename();
          System.out.println("image" +keyName);       
          String filePath = "D:/bhanu/images%20(4).JPG";
          System.out.println("filePath" +filePath);
          String amazonFileUploadLocationOriginal=existingBucketName;
          System.out.println("hello");
          AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
          System.out.println("hello1");
          FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
          System.out.println("hello2");
          ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
          System.out.println("hello3");
          PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(amazonFileUploadLocationOriginal, keyName, stream, objectMetadata);
          System.out.println("hello4");
          PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);

        System.out.println("Etag:" + result.getETag() + "-->" + result);


        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a version of `putObject` that accepts an `InputStream` instead of a file path:

> `putObject(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input, ObjectMetadata metadata)`
>
> Uploads the specified input stream and object metadata to Amazon S3 under the specified bucket and key name.

See: [putObject documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata))

Comment: sir in this line String filePath = "D:/bhanu/images%20(4).JPG";

Comment: i don't want to pass the path i want to pass content of image (bytes)

Comment: i am able to get bytes data using spring mvc BufferedOutputStream stream =  new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(keyName+bytes)));                 
          stream.write(bytes);